# ARMAX with lagged exogenous variables

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, arima

I have difficulties finding the implementation of ARIMAX, ARMAX model where the exogenous variable would be also included with the time lags:

$X_{t}=\varepsilon_{t}+\sum_{i=1}^{p} \varphi_{i} X_{t-i}+\sum_{i=1}^{q} \theta_{i} \varepsilon_{t-i}-\sum_{i=1}^{p} \beta_{i} u_{t-i}$

Could you please advise on which software uses this approach for ARMAX/ARIMAX?
Statmodels from python return only one coefficient for an exogenous variable called sigma, while the model here would ideally return the coefficients for all lagged exogenous values. I suppose the order of the lagged exogenous variables would be the same as the AR order, but I am not sure about this either.
Is this what is called transfer function model rather than ARIMAX?

Comment: ARMAX models with lagged values of exogenous variables are called ARDL (AR Distributed Lag) models. You can search the implementation of ARDL for whichever statistical software that you are using.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification! I suppose that it doesn't have Moving average component.

Comment: Good point. I guess there is surely a version of ARDL models that allow for MA also. Frankly I have never implemented such a model but I am sure some library in Python/R will have it.